# JSON encode gives "malformed json" error on a file that is completely valid JSON

Tags: php, json

So, i'm creating php page that sends JSON data to other app. I got the code working, but then it mysteriosly stopped working. I'm getting malformed JSON error, even though JSON validator says my file is fine. When i try other JSON file it works fine.

Here's the JSON:

```
[{
    "value1": "Example",
    "value2": "Other example"
}]
```

And here's the PHP (don't mind the Finnish variable names):

```
$url = "velat.json";
$velat_json = file_get_contents($url);
$velatarray = array();
$velat = json_decode($velat_json);


 switch (json_last_error()) {
case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
    echo ' - No errors';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
    echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
    echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
    echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
    echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
break;
case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
    echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
break;
default:
    echo ' - Unknown error';
break;
}

foreach($velat as $velka){
    $velatarray[] = $velka;
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); //CORS
header("Content-type: application/json");
print json_encode($velatarray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

What's really weird is that it USED to work. I added feature that allowed me to add new items to JSON file via angular app and even that worked. Then i deleted the added item manually and tried encoding it in utf-8 and suddenly it stopped working, even after i undid all changes and reversed it back to bare bones. How is this happening?

Edit: fixed, BOM was causing the issue

Comment: Clearly the text in the file isn't quite what you've quoted. My guess is that a BOM slipped into the beginning of the file and is being returned by `file_get_contents`. Look closely at the first character of `$velat_json`.

Comment: Oh right, it seems that i changed file to regular UTF-8 which caused the error. Changing it to UTF-8 without BOM fixed the issue. Thanks!